# Display last few graphs using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, oracle10g, flot

I want to get last 3 graph using refresh where the page automatically refresh in every 10 seconds. Here in this code when the page is refreshing automatically it start showing from beginning but i don't want that way.When the page will refresh every time it must show its last 3 graph. As here only 4 data available, it must show only D2 to D4 graph only even after refresh. When new data will be available it will display D3 to D5(which is not available right now) graph. How can i get last three graph after refreshing the page automatically?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" Content="10">
<title>Graph</title>
<style>

    div.placeholder{
    width: 500px;
    height:250px
    }


</style>

<?php
include("mydb.php");
// run query

$sql1 = "select * from tab where to_char(D,'dd/mm')='25-7'";
$stid1=oci_parse($conn, $sql1);
// set array
$arr1 = array();

if(!$stid1){
$e=oci_error($conn);
trigger_error(htmlentities($e[message],ENT_QUOTES),E_USER_ERROR);
}

$r1=oci_execute($stid1);

if(!$r1){
$e=oci_error($stid1);
trigger_error(htmlentities($e[message],ENT_QUOTES),E_USER_ERROR);
}

// look through query
while($row = oci_fetch_array($stid1,OCI_ASSOC)){

  // add each row returned into an array
  $arr1[] = array((strtotime($row['D'])*1000) , (float)$row['D1']);

}

?>

<?php
include("mydb.php");
// run query

$sql2 = "select * from tab where to_char(D,'dd/mm')='26-7'";
$stid2=oci_parse($conn, $sql2);
// set array
$arr2 = array();
if(!$stid1){
$e=oci_error($conn);
trigger_error(htmlentities($e[message],ENT_QUOTES),E_USER_ERROR);
}

$r2=oci_execute($stid2);

if(!$r2){
$e=oci_error($stid2);
trigger_error(htmlentities($e[message],ENT_QUOTES),E_USER_ERROR);
}

// look through query
while($row = oci_fetch_array($stid2,OCI_ASSOC)){

  // add each row returned into an array

  $arr2[] = array((strtotime($row['D'])*1000) , (float)$row['D1']);

}

?>


<?php
include("mydb.php");
// run query

$sql3 = "select * from tab where to_char(D,'dd/mm')='27-8'";
$stid3=oci_parse($conn, $sql3);
// set array
$arr3 = array();
if(!$stid3){
$e=oci_error($conn);
trigger_error(htmlentities($e[message],ENT_QUOTES),E_USER_ERROR);
}

$r3=oci_execute($stid3);

if(!$r3){
$e=oci_error($stid3);
trigger_error(htmlentities($e[message],ENT_QUOTES),E_USER_ERROR);
}

// look through query
while($row = oci_fetch_array($stid3,OCI_ASSOC)){

  // add each row returned into an array
  $arr3[] = array((strtotime($row['D'])*1000) , (float)$row['D1']);

}

?>


<?php
include("mydb.php");
// run query

$sql4 = "select * from dat where to_char(D,'dd/mm')='28-9'";
$stid4=oci_parse($conn, $sql4);
// set array
$arr4 = array();
if(!$stid4){
$e=oci_error($conn);
trigger_error(htmlentities($e[message],ENT_QUOTES),E_USER_ERROR);
}

$r4=oci_execute($stid4);

if(!$r4){
$e=oci_error($stid4);
trigger_error(htmlentities($e[message],ENT_QUOTES),E_USER_ERROR);
}

// look through query
while($row = oci_fetch_array($stid4,OCI_ASSOC)){

  // add each row returned into an array

  $arr4[] = array((strtotime($row['D'])*1000) , (float)$row['D1']);

}
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.symbol.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.axislabels.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.time.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var interval=2000;
function getdata(){

var data1=<?php echo json_encode($arr1); ?>;
var data2=<?php echo json_encode($arr2); ?>;
var data3=<?php echo json_encode($arr3); ?>;
var data4=<?php echo json_encode($arr4); ?>;

return [data1,data2,data3,data4];
}
var options={
                
                series: {
                        lines: {
                                show: true,
                                lineWidth: 2,
                                fill: true
                                },
                        points:{
                                show: "triangle"
                                }
                        },
                xaxis: {
                                                    
                            axisLabel: "Time",
                            axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                            axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
                            axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
                            axisLabelPadding: 10
                        },
                    yaxis: {
                            
                            axisLabel: "Data loading",
                            axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                            axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
                            axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
                            axisLabelPadding: 6
                        },
               legend: {        
                            labelBoxBorderColor: "#B0D5FF"
                        },
                    grid: {
                            hoverable: true, 
                            clickable: true,
                            backgroundColor: { 
                                                colors: ["#B0D5FF", "#5CA8FF"] 
                                            }
                            }
};
   $(document).ready(function () {

            var dataset=[
              { 
                label: "D1", 
                data: getdata()[0], 
                points: { 
                            symbol: "triangle"
                        } 

             },     
            {
                label: "D2",
                data: getdata()[1],
                points: {
                            symbol: "circle"
                        }
             },         
            {
                label: "D3",
                data: getdata()[2],
                points: {
                            symbol: "triangle"
                        }
             },
            {
                label: "D4",
                data: getdata()[3],
                points: {
                            symbol: "triangle"
                        }
             }
            ];

var counter=0;
for(var i=1,j=0;i<dataset.length,j<$('div.placeholder').length;i++,j++){
    $.plot("div.placeholder:eq(" + j + ")", [dataset[j]], options);
    counter=i;
}

function update() {
                
    $('div.placeholder:visible:first').hide();
    $('div.placeholder:last').after($('<div>').addClass('placeholder'));
    $.plot("div.placeholder:last", [dataset[counter++]], options);
    
    if(dataset.length > counter) {
        setTimeout(update, interval);

    }       
 }
 
    setTimeout(update, interval);



});

</script>

</head>

<body>
    <center>
    <h3><b><u>Chart</u></b></h3>


<div class="placeholder"></div>
<div class="placeholder"></div>
<div class="placeholder"></div>

</center>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are mixing server-side and client-side handling of your data which leads to problems / confusion. Try to get a clear process from your database to the charts. For example only give three datasets to the page and refresh the page when you want to show new data.

Comment: @raidri I'm not able to get your point. can you please explain in details.

Comment: @Raidri Did you mean 'var dataset=[{label: "D1", data: getdata()[0],          points: {  symbol: "triangle" } 
}, { label: "D2",  data: getdata()[1],  points: { symbol: "circle"  } },         
 { label: "D3",
   data: getdata()[2],
   points: {
 symbol: "triangle"
}
 }];' then when new data will be available , then remove d1 and insert d4 dataset? if so then every time for every new graph we have remove old dataset from coding. right? Then won't it become a hard coding? Is there any other way?

Comment: please suggest me what i suppose to do. @Raidri